# Scala - Save a data frame to text file without [ ]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

When i save a Dataframe to a text file it gets saved with `[]` 
for example i have a data frame:

```
9206E599-2E07-439E-9C01-A6714E779D11
D607E87F-FB90-4F2B-8A99-335AE4F5C97F
```

when i do `myDataFrame.rdd.saveAsTextFile("My Path")` i get

```
[9206E599-2E07-439E-9C01-A6714E779D11]
[D607E87F-FB90-4F2B-8A99-335AE4F5C97F]
```

is there a way to remove those brackets.

Comment: why you want them to be removed? when you load this df from file back again, you will be able to get back your df.

Comment: i need to subtract this dataframe with another, so need to maintain them in same format BTW they wont be removed when i load them back

Comment: can you show your DF's schema? (you can use `myDataFrame.printSchema()`)

Comment: `root
 |-- DeviceIDs: string (nullable = true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it.

```
val df: DataFrame = ???
df.rdd.map(r => r.getString(0)).saveAsTextFile("My Path")
```

The issue is your RDD contains org.apache.spark.sql.Row objects. When these are 'toStringed' they have those square braces on either side. You want to extract the data out of the Row object into a String.

Answer (score 5):

A simpler option - just use the standard Dataframe `write` API without converting to RDD:

```
myDataFrame.write.text("My Path")
```